# Continue mapping after stream collect

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How do I continue the stream mapping after collect:

```
public Bus createBus(List<String> passengers) {
   return passengers.stream()
             .map(name -> new Person(name))
             .collect(Collectors.toList())
             .map(personList -> new Bus(personList))
}
```

Above obviously does not work. How to make it work elegantly without using any variables in the method body?

Edit:
Constructor is Bus(List persons).

Comment: Does the `Bus` constructor take a single `Person` or a `List<Person>`as a parameter?

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52386039/2711488). If you want to avoid variables, you may further replace `name -> new Person(name)` with `Person::new` and `personList -> new Bus(personList)` with `Bus::new`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the Collector from [Collectors.collectingAndThen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) to perform an additional finishing transformation :

```
public Bus createBus(List<String> passengers) {
    return passengers.stream()
            .map(name -> new Person(name))
            .collect(Collectors
                    .collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), Bus::new));
}
```

Comment: there isn't a `peoples` btw, it's `people`

Comment: Yes, this is what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

Since `collect` returns a collection, you need to open a new stream on the new collected list:

```
 list.stream().map(name -> new Person(name))
         .collect(Collectors.toList())
         .stream()....
```

or simply remove the `collect`:  `list.stream().map(name -> new Person(name)).map(...)`. That would make much more sense in your case

Comment: i know, thanks for the hint, its really a bad wording:D. corrected

Comment: hmm... I don't really get what you mean here. I need to give the collected list as a argument for the Bus (not individual persons).

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I didn't get that, then collectingAndThen () will help you as shown in the other answers. I thought it was just about open a steam on a collected list.

Answer (score 1):

`map` will iterate over each `Person` in your list. Your `Bus`, instead, seems to need the whole list as a parameter. As it is, you try to create a new `Bus` for each name in the `passengers` list.

You can either pass the collected list directly to the constructor:

```
public Bus createBus(List<String> passengers) {
   return new Bus(passengers.stream()
             .map(name -> new Person(name))
             .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

or store it in a variable (which I think is clearer):

```
public Bus createBus(List<String> passengers) {
   List<Person> persons = passengers.stream()
             .map(name -> new Person(name))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
   return new Bus(persons);
}
```

Comment: he stated that he does not want to use variables:) (though its much more nice to read with a local variable)

Comment: @ItFreak Yes, and there is no variable in the first block of code. But I still think that using a local variable is nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `Bus` has a `List` of `Person` objects:

```
public Bus createBus(List<String> passengers) {
   return new Bus(passengers.stream().map(name -> new Person(name)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Another option:

```
public Bus createBus(List<String> passengers) {
    return new Bus(getPersons(passengers));
}

private List<Person> getPersons(List<String> passengers) {
    return passengers.stream().map(name -> new Person(name)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be achieved in such a way if you don't want any extra variables being introduced:

```
    public Bus createBus(List<String> passengers) {
         return passengers.stream()
                .map(Person::new)
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), Stream::of))
                .map(Bus::new)
                .reduce((first, second) -> second)
                .orElseThrow();
    }
```

Collecting creates one set, which is then converted to a stream again. Stream of 1 element in this case. However it is still a stream, so if you want to return just one `Bus` (not a list of `Bus`), it has to be reduced somehow. Here I just reduced it to one as the stream will have one element anyway.

`reduce` operation returns `Optional<Bus>`, so you have to check if it's there, when you get it. For simplicity, this code will just throw, when Optional is empty.